# How do I assign OnRowCommand to multiple IDs ASP.net and VB.net Backend

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, variables, backend

I have 2 GridViews with separate IDs

I need the backend code to update the one being viewed when a button is clicked.

`    Protected Sub savestatus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

```
    Dim btn As Button = TryCast(sender, Button)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = CType(((CType(sender, Button)).NamingContainer), GridViewRow)
    Dim rowindex As Integer = row.RowIndex
    Dim code As String = GridView1.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Values(0).ToString()
    Dim type As Int32 = GridView1.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Values(1)
    Dim statusid As Integer

    Dim checkLocked, checkerror As CheckBox
    ' For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    checkLocked = CType(GridView1.Rows(rowindex).FindControl("lock"), CheckBox)
    checkerror = CType(GridView1.Rows(rowindex).FindControl("error"), CheckBox)
    If checkerror.Checked Then ' error
        statusid = 2
    End If
    If checkLocked.Checked Then
        statusid = 3
    End If`
```

How do I make the GridView1 a variable depending on which grid view the button is pressed in.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it would have helped a lot to at least show the button and a few rows of the gridview markup.

There are about 10 ways to do this. (really !!!).

However, in your case, two check boxes, and you need actions to occur when a check box is changed – AND say change the other one!!

Now I am using two check boxes – but it could be a text box or whatever I change.

So, say I have this grid markup
Some columns + TWO un-bound check boxes.

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Province" HeaderText="Province" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Good">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkGood" runat="server" 
                            AutoPostBack="true"
                            OnCheckedChanged="chkGood_CheckedChanged"
                            MyRowID ='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bad">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBad" runat="server" 
                            AutoPostBack="true"
                            OnCheckedChanged="chkBad_CheckedChanged"
                            MyRowID ='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Ok, and now the code to load the grid:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If IsPostBack = False Then

        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT ID, HotelName, City, Province from tblHotels",
                      New SqlConnection(My.Settings.Test3))
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
            GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

And thus we have this:

[image]

Ok, so far - very simple.

Now note CLOSE at the markup for the two check boxes.

And while dropping a button or whatever on a normal form - you can then double click to JUMP to the code behind event/stub?

Well, for buttons or whatever you drop INSIDE of a grid, you can't double click on the control to create + jump to the code behind stub.

But, WHILE in the markup, you can start typing the event, and you get this:

[image]

Note VERY careful how the intel-sense pops up a option to create the event. So click on that option. Nothing seems to happen, but NOW we get a code stub behind.

So, we have this code stub for the chkOk event:

```
Protected Sub chkGood_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim ckBox As CheckBox = sender
    Dim RowID As Integer = ckBox.Attributes.Item("MyRowID")
    Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(RowID)

    If ckBox.Checked = True Then
        ' do whatever if true - say un-check the "bad" check box
        Dim ckBoxBad As CheckBox = gvRow.FindControl("chkBad")
        ckBoxBad.Checked = False
    Else
        ' code here if the user just un-checked the "good" check box
    End If

End Sub
```

Note a few things:

We pick up the button click - then shove it into a checkbox control. This is just a lot easier to get the check box value, and our CUSTOM MyRowID

(and this works if it was a button for example).

We then get the custom made up Attribute we added called "MyRowID"

```
MyRowID ='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
```

You can see the expression in the Markup - it passes the current row id. Sometimes, I'll pass other values from the row and you can do this like this:

```
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBad" runat="server" 
        AutoPostBack="true"
        OnCheckedChanged="chkBad_CheckedChanged"
        MyRowID ='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' 
        MyPKID =  '<%# Eval("ID") %>'  />
```

So in above, I pass both RowID and a custom MyPKID (so the Eval() expression can be used to pass any valid data row avaialble at binding time. Its often handy then having to grab and mess with a data row - you JUST grab the button from sender - and you don't care about gridview or anything else to get a few extra values. (just a FYI tip). So for example, I REALLY don't want the PK row id as the first row. So I could remove it and STILL use the above idea to PASS the pk row id - all columns can be used - even if a control is NOT in the grid - as long as the column exists during the data binding process - you can grab it.

So, now we pick up the current GridRow - and we are free to modify whatever we want on that row.

In my simple example, we pick up the OTHER check box - and un-check if it was checked. But we could say update other things on that row.

And I did the same for the chkBad check box. And I have really the same as the first chkBox code stub. Eg this:

```
Protected Sub chkBad_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim ckBox As CheckBox = sender
    Dim RowID As Integer = ckBox.Attributes.Item("MyRowID")

    Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(RowID)

    If ckBox.Checked = True Then
        ' user checked the bad box, un-check the good one
        Dim ckBoxGood As CheckBox = gvRow.FindControl("chkGood")
        ckBoxGood.Checked = False
    Else
        ' code here if the user just un-checked the "bad" check box
    End If

End Sub
```

So in above we just hard right past the GridView bult in events.

So in above, if you check one box and the other is checked - we un-check it. Needless to say, I would use a button list, or a checkbox list, and that above code would of course then not be required. But it still a good example on how to pluck/get the current row. And then get/pluck controls from that row.

Note that for the first 3 rows (the databound), you can NOT use findControl, and they are referenced using the gvRow.Cells(0) (starting at 0 to N columns. So no findcontrol is required for these databound columns or autogenerated ones. They do NOT have a name - you have to use number starting at 0 in the cells collection. Of course for "templated" controls that we added as per above? Then you do in fact use findcontrol as per above.